# Error al recuperar valores antigüos de una tabla en un formulario de modificación

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo una tabla Oferta, que tiene los siguientes parametros:

```
Schema::create('ofertas', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('titulo');
        $table->text('descripcion');
        $table->string('empresa');
        $table->string('sector');
        $table->date('fecha_limite');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

La historia es que he creado una a un metodo con el cual modificar los valores de una oferta. Este es su código:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Modifique los datos de la oferta</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{route('oferta.cambiar',$oferta)}}" novalidate>
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="titulo" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Nombre de la oferta de trabajo</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="titulo" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('titulo') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="titulo" value="{{ $oferta->titulo }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('titulo'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('titulo') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="descripcion" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Descripción del trabajo</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="descripcion" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('descripcion') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="descripcion" value="{{ $oferta->descripcion }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('descripcion'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('descripcion') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="empresa" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Empresa en la que se trabajara</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="empresa" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('empresa') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="empresa" value="{{ $oferta->empresa }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('empresa'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('empresa') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="sector" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Sector en el que se trabajara</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select id="sector" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('sector') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="sector" value="{{ $oferta->sector }}" required autofocus> <!-- value="{{ $oferta->sector }}" falla aqui, dejando la primera opción. Mira como solucionarlo -->
                                    @foreach($sector as $sec)
                                        <option value="{{$sec->nombre}}">{{$sec->nombre}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>

                                @if ($errors->has('sector'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('sector') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="fecha_limite" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Fecha límite para aceptar la oferta</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="fecha_limite" type="date" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('fecha_limite') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="fecha_limite" value="{{ $oferta->fecha_limite }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('fecha_limite'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('fecha_limite') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Crear Oferta
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Esta vista crea un formulario que muestra los antiguos valores de la fila que vamos a modificar.

Ahora, aqui tenemos una fila.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al ir a la vista para modificarla, me encuentro esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La variable "sector", que es una lista en lugar de una caja de texto, ignora el valor indicado en `value="{{ $oferta->sector }}"`, por lo que siempre muestra el primer valor de la lista.
¿Como corrijo esto?

Edito: Un detalle que me olvide, la tabla de los sectores:

```
    Schema::create('sectors', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

De esta tabla se saca el sector que ira en la tabla Oferta. Para no liarme demasiado, no cree la relación foranea, sino un string.

Comment: ¿Por qué en la tabla ofertas el campo sector es una cadena ? no debería ser le id de la tabla sector es decir un entero positivo?

Comment: Simplemente para no complicar demasiado la tabla. He editado mi pregunta para añadir más datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solo está guardando el texto del sector en su tabla ofertas, lo cuál es incorrecto. debería ser un entero positivo con el `id` del sector. si es solo así debería comparar para saber que opción seleccionará en el `select`

Si deja tal cuál está su código simplemente debería comparar los nombres de los sectores para saber que `option` seleccionar con el atributo `selected`

Posible Ejm

```
<select id="sector" type="text" class="form-control
    {{ $errors->has('sector') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="sector" required autofocus> 
     @foreach($sector as $sec)
        <option value="{{$sec->nombre }} "
            {{($sec->nombre === $oferta->sector ) ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $sec->nombre}}</option>
    @endforeach
 </select>
```

Insisto que debería guardar el id en la tabla ofertas y no un texto *(a menos que se me escape un detalle que no está en su pregunta)*

Comment: Pues gracias, ya he logrado arreglarlo.